# Unable to access rabbitmq-management portal - over local network ( docker installation )

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

I have installed docker on my local machine using the following command

`docker run -d --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 -p 5673:5673 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

I have no issues with the installation and I am able to access rabbitmq management console on my local machine using `localhost` and `ip address`

`http://localhost:15672/` OR
`http://192.168.1.111:15672/#/`

Both of these URLs are working fine on the machine where `RabbitMQ` is installed.

Now, **I want to access this management console from some other machine ( IP address `192.168.1.116`) which is in the same network.**

When I tried to access `management console` using `IP (192.168.1.111)` address I am getting following error:-

```
This site can't be reached.  192.168.1.111 took too long to respond. Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I have verified that machine is reachable and I was able to ping `192.168.1.111` (machine where RabbitMQ is installed through docker)  from `192.168.1.116`

Below are details of docker installation

```
C:\Users\heman>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:43:18 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:27 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
 Kubernetes:
  Version:          v1.16.6-beta.0
  StackAPI:         v1alpha3
```

Comment: It was a firewall issue.  I have to open a port 15672 to allow traffic from other computers.